# store defaultstate with redux observable middleware

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-observable, redux-middleware

I am making a redux observable epic as middleware, and also want to provide a default state to store. At some places I have seen applyMiddleware as third argument to createStore function whereas at some places it is second argument. How can I acheive this?

I am trying this

```
const defaultState = {users: []};
const store = createStore(rootReducer, defaultState, applyMiddleWare(middleWare));
```

My main App looks like this

```
import { bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actionCreators from '../actions/actionCreator';
import Main from './Main';
import 'rxjs';

function mapStatesToProps(state) {
    return {
        users: state.users,
        error: state.error
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
}

const App = connect(mapStatesToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);

export default App;
```

But this is not setting the default state.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you are supposed to pass the default state as the second argument. There must be a bug in code that isn’t provided here.

Have you tried reproducing the problem outside of your app? If you have and can share that complete code to reproduce, I can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was happening because mismatch of reducer name and default state property,

My reducer name was `User` whereas I was trying to add `users` property to default state. After making both of them `users` it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using "compose" in 3rd parameter, something like below?

```
import { compose } from 'redux';

const defaultState = {users: []};
const store = createStore(rootReducer, defaultState, compose(applyMiddleWare(middleWare)));
```